# aws-sdk putObject Access Denied Request.extractError

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following policy attached to the IAM user I am using.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1468642330000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-648213736065/documents/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Problem is when I do something like:

```
return readFile(file.path)
  .then(function(buffer) {
    var s3obj = s3.putObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: `documents/${destFileName}`,
      Body: buffer
    });
    return s3obj.promise();
  });
```

I get:

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Whats wrong here?

---

Looks like when I use `listBuckets`, I get contents from my other S3 account. Seems like the way I configure the SDK is incorrect?

Comment: Why the Key: `documents/${destFileName}` is the destination file?

Comment: Are you sure the target bucket exists?

Comment: @KarenB, yes I copy and pasted

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the issue, looks like its using the `[default]` profile specified in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

I found that I need to configure AWS like this:

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: appConfig.aws.accessId,
  secretAccessKey: appConfig.aws.secretKey,
  logger: process.stdout
});
```

I was originally setting

```
AWS.config.accessKeyId = ...
```