# Aws cognito create user by admin nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am using javascript sdk amazon-cognito-identity-js and i am trying to create a user in cognito in nodejs but error is coming 
below is my code:-

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")
var params = {
    UserPoolId: "id",
    Username: req.body.username,
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
    ForceAliasCreation: false,
    TemporaryPassword: req.body.password,
    UserAttributes: [
      { Name: "name", Value: req.body.name },
      { Name: "email", Value: req.body.user_email}
    ],
 };
let client = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
client.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("EE",err);
      //  reject(err);
    } else {
        console.log("DDD",data);
        //resolve(data);
    }
})
```

But i am getting this error using the code:-

> EE { UnknownError: Not Found at Request.extractError
>   (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27) }

Please Help me Out to figure out this issue.

Comment: try this command on console "npm i aws-sdk"

Comment: same issue no change

Comment: just go through this error may be you are facing same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411915/aws-sdk-putobject-access-denied-request-extracterror

It seems to be endpoing configuration issue as given in the AWS forum answer.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=804631

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution.

Pre-requirement 
If you want to use the credential in aws-sdk (Manual Process)
 1. Create IAM User and Assign a Cognito role to your user.
 2. Generate Access Key and Secret Key for that user.
 3. Use that Access Key and Secret Key in aws-sdk.

Like This,

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "YOURKEY",
    secretAccessKey: "YOURSECRET",
    region: "YOURREGION"
});
```

Create object of **CognitoIdentityServiceProvider** class

```
const COGNITO_CLIENT = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2016-04-19",
  region: "us-east-1"
});


var poolData = {
    UserPoolId: "XXXXXXXXX",
    Username: "kurulezomi@themailpro.net",
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
    TemporaryPassword: "Abc@321",
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: "email",
        Value: "kuri@themailpro.net"
      },
      {
        Name: "email_verified",
        Value: "true"
      }
    ]
  };
  COGNITO_CLIENT.adminCreateUser(poolData, (error, data) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(data);
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  });
```

Or else you can directly assign  IAM Role to your EC2 Instance in that case you do not need to set credentials in **AWS.config** Section.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property

Answer (score 0):

ABOUT THIS NODE.JS EXAMPLE: This example works with the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 2 (v2).
Purpose:
admin-create-user.js demonstrates how an administrator can use Amazon Cognito to create a user.

**Inputs:**

- USERPOOLID
- EMAIL

**AWS configuration**

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId : "Your accessKeyId ",
  secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
});
```

**CREATE COGNITO_CLIENT**

```
const COGNITO_CLIENT = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2022-10-03",
  region: "us-east-1",
});
```

**CREATE USER**

```
const createUser = async (user) => {
  try {
    const { emailId, password } = user;
    const cognitoParams = {
      UserPoolId: userPoolId,
      Username: emailId,
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: "email",
          Value: emailId,
        },
        {
          Name: "email_verified",
          Value: "true",
        },
      ],
      TemporaryPassword: password || "Password@123456789",
    };

    console.log(cognitoParams.TemporaryPassword);

    let response = await COGNITO_CLIENT.adminCreateUser(
      cognitoParams
    ).promise();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    return "user created";
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

And for **AWS SDK v3** and **ES6**:

Install the **Library**

```
npm install @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider --save
```

Import the **Module**

```
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, AdminCreateUserCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
```

Create the **Client**

```
const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: 'eu-west-1' });
```

Create the **User**

```
const command = new AdminCreateUserCommand({
      UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
      Username: EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'],
      TemporaryPassword: TEMPORARY_PASSWORD
    });

let response = await cognitoClient.send(command);
```

Note that you'll need to have `cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser` permission for this to work.